# Youtube video is not playing

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube

The following error is shown and youtube video is not playing

initialVideoId can't be null.
'package:youtube_player_flutter/src/utils/youtube_player_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 162 pos 16: 'initialVideoId != null

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

class YoutubePlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoUrl;
  final UniqueKey newKey;
  YoutubePlayerWidget({@required this.videoUrl, this.newKey})
      : super(key: newKey);
  @override
  _YoutubePlayerWidgetState createState() => _YoutubePlayerWidgetState();
}

class _YoutubePlayerWidgetState extends State<YoutubePlayerWidget> {
  String videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?";

  YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  void initState() {
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(videoUrl));

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                YoutubePlayerBuilder(
                  player: YoutubePlayer(
                    controller: _controller,
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                  ),
                  builder: (context, player) {
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[player],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your video url must be: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ID_HERE`

Because you need to pass in the id in the `v=`.

`watch?` is the page to watch a video without id, it will go to the page without any video to play, so `watch?` alone is not correct.

Comment: This is to play a single video. If i want to play some more videos means what shall i do? For example Learning management system application, there is one lesson with many chapter with videos?

Comment: how to fetch video from backend i.e website

Comment: this is it for the link i helped you about the syntax of the links in youtube :)

Comment: @indhumathi to play multiple videos, you have to find your own way, youtube only serves 1 video at a time

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube link which you shared in the string 'videoUrl' is an invalid link.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the video link you provided does not have an ID

Example of a link with an ID

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-uBD7cHmtI
```